# Objective-c Regex format creditcard

Tags: objective-c, regex, whitespace

I have a list of card numbers 1234123412341234 but I need a regex that formats it with whitespaces like "123 123 123 123".

So every 4 character add a whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with Ruby (tested):

```
s = '1234123412341234'
s.sub!(/(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})/, '\1 \2 \3 \4')
print s   # => "1234 1234 1234 1234"
```

I'm no Obj-C dude, but with RegexKit or RegexKit Lite, the code should be (untested) something like:

```
[string stringByMatching:@"(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})" replace:1 withString:@"$1 $2 $3 $4"]
```

Some more reading:

- [Regex in a Nutshell](http://www.bitcetera.com/en/techblog/2008/04/01/regex-in-a-nutshell/)
- [RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) and [RegexKit Lite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/)
- [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (iOS 4 and above only)