# How can I validate the contents of a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios, validation, uitextfield, symbols

I have a problem when I post text from a  UITeField to PHP, if I leave a space or using strange symbols (ie. !,@,#,^,&,{}...)

Can I block the IBaction not to send this useless text to server?

```
- (IBAction)sendeTextToServer:(id)sender{
   if(textfield.text has any space or other symbols inside){
       //Block the text send to server
   }
   else
      //Send the text to server to do something.
}
```

How can I validate the contents of a UITextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression!  I have used [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) in many projects with much success.

EDIT: Here's a link form another answer on [how to use it](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=54).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393377/objective-c-regex-format-creditcard

Comment: thanks,I'm looking this page now,still try to understanding now

Comment: and: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html